# Strange behavior of OTP gen_tcp with settings {packet,4} and using NodeJS "frame-stream'' for TCP communication

Tags: node.js, tcp, erlang, erlang-otp, gen-tcp

I've been struggling for a while to get my messages framed correctly between my NodeJS server and my erlang gen_tcp server. I was using {packet,line} successfully until I had to send large data messages and needed to switch to message size framing.

I set gen_tcp to **{packet,2}**

and I'm using the library from:
**https://github.com/davedoesdev/frame-stream**
for the NodeJS tcp decode side. It is ALSO set to packet size option 2
and I have tried packet size option 4.

I saw for any messages with a length under 127 characters this setup works well, but any messages longer than this has a problem.

I ran a test by sending longer and longer messages from gen_tcp and then reading out the first four bytes received on the NodeJS side:

on message 127:
HEADER: 0 0 0 127
Frame length 127

on message 128:
HEADER: 0 0 0 239   <----- This should be 128
Frame length 239    <----- This should be 128

Theories:

- Some character encoding mismatch since it's on the number 128 (likely?)
- Some error in either gen_tcp or the library (highly unlikely?)
- Voodoo magic curse that makes me work on human-rights day (most likely)

**Data from wireshark shows the following:**

The header bytes are encoded properly by gen_tcp past 128 characters since the hex values proceed as follows:

```
[00][7e][...]  (126 length)
[00][7f][...]  (127 length)
[00][80][...]  (128 length)
[00][81][...]  (129 length)
```

So it must be that the error lies when the library on the NodeJS side calls the Node readUInt16BE(0) or readUInt32BE(0) functions. But I checked the endieness and both are big-endian.

If the header bytes are [A,B] then, in binary, this error occurs after
[00000000 01111111]

In other words, readUInt16BE(0) reads [000000000 10000000] as 0xef ? which is not even an endian option...?

Thank you for any help in how to solve this.

Kind Regards

Dale

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the problem was caused by setting the socket to receive on UTF-8 encoding which supports ascii up to 127.

Dont do this: socket.setEncoding('utf8').

It seems obvious now but that one line of code is hard to spot.